# How to find out the blending mode?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blending

I'm trying to mimic a grid background that has rows and columns of the same color. The rows are filled with R226, B242 and G249. When the rows cross the columns we get R214 B237 and G247.

I'm failing to understand which blending mode could produce this kind of results. It certainly not multiply or linear burn?!

[image: Sample]

Comment: It could merely be **opacity** causing the stacked appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Got a workaround...

1. Created a **layer mask** of the columns layer in the rows layer
2. Selected the columns layer CTRL+Click and then the option **Intersect mask with selection**
3. Filled the resulting selection with R214 B237 G247